# What is a 'Cartesian' in the context of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a better understanding of what a 'Cartesian' is.  The following is a quote from an answer from `xQbert` to [a question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436959/not-getting-all-records-from-table-a-in-left-join):

> When working with left (or outer) joins you have to consider when the
>   data limit is imposed vs when the Cartesian is created.

Is the 'Cartesian' xQbert is referring to the same as the 'Cartesian Product' I so dread when I forget to specify the criteria to join tables on?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: That Wikipedia link was so helpful in explaining what a Cartesian Product was to me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Answer (score 1):

First, don't let joins scare you, respect them.

```
Select
      a.field1,
      ...
      x.field2
   from
      SomeTable a
         JOIN AnotherTable x
            on a.SomeKey = x.SomeKey
   where
      blah...
```

The Wikipedia goes into all sorts of what-if scenarios and mathematical references, etc.  I will try to throw into simpler terms.  When doing joins, just know what the "key" elements are between the tables in question.  In most cases it will be by some common Key ID (customerID, orderID, itemID, etc).

So, in its simplest sense, if you have a system of orders and customers and do something like

```
select o.orderID, c.CustomerID
   from Orders o, Customers c
```

No join will result in for every order it will join to every customer.  So if you have 5 orders and 3 customers, you will get 15 entries.

Ex:

```
Orders                  |     Customers
OrderID  CustomerID     |     CustomerID  Name
1        A              |     A           Adam
2        B              |     B           Bill
3        C              |     C           Casey
4        B              |     
5        C              |
```

You would get

```
1-A
1-B
1-C
2-A
2-B
2-C
...
5-A
5-B
5-C
```

Now, notice that two customers each had two orders.  Since you know the common key between the tables, you will only get the 5 entries with

```
select o.orderID, c.CustomerID, c.Name
   from 
      Orders o
         JOIN Customers c
            on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

And you will get what is expected...

```
1 A Adam
2 B Bill
3 C Casey
4 B Bill
5 C Casey
```

When getting into left-joins (or right-joins), the premise still holds true.  Always apply the KNOWN key relations.  If they match, great (inner join), if not (left-join), then the record in the left-side table of the query will still be included even if no match to the right.  I recently saw an example of join clarifications and will try to find it too.

Now with this basic explanation, consider having 3 tables in your system... each with 5000, 2000 and 3000 records respectively.  If you query WITHOUT the join conditions between the respective tables you would end up with 30,000,000,000 records and obviously be a mess.

So, when writing queries, I always try to start this way.  Look at all the tables I need to get from piece in table A all the way to something in table D.  I need to look at whatever the relationships are between each of the tables always have them in your query (provided you need all the tables).  Once you get the tables and now all the columns you want, then consider the CRITERIA you want.  These can be applied in the where clause (typically for the first table), but can also include the other aliases in the query too.  However, this can be a bit tricky especially when dealing with left-joins.  If you have certain criteria that is applicable to one of the joined tables, you can add logical "AND" criteria at that level.

Also, when doing queries, get in the habit of using aliases for tables that are long named to simplify query readability.  Also, always qualify table.column or alias.column in your queries that have multiple tables.  If people are trying to help you and they don't know what column is in what table, it makes it harder to follow... let alone someone after you taking over or updating queries.

Good luck.